# How to quote command substitution so that it behaves like "$@"?

Tags: bash, quoting, command-substitution

`$*` is equivalent to `$1 $2 $3...` - split on all spaces.

`"$*"` is equivalent to `"$1 $2 $3..."` - no splitting here.

`"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2" "$3"...` - split on arguments (every argument is quoted individually).

**How to quote `$(command)`  so that it treats output lines of the command in the same way `"$@"` treats arguments?**

The problem I want to solve:

I have a backup function that takes files by arguments and backups each of them (e.g.: `backup file1 file_2 "file 3"`). I want to quickly backup files that are returned by another command.

`mycmd` returns three files (one per line): *file1*, *file_2* and *file 3* (containing a space). If I ran the following command:

```
backup $(mycmd)
```

it would be equivalent to running `backup file1 file_2 file 3` and it would result in an error because of non-existing files *file* and *3*. However running it this way:

```
backup "$(mycmd)"
```

is equivalent to run:

```
backup "file1
file_2
file 3"
```

None of them is good enough.

**How can I use command substitution to get a call equivalent to: `backup "file1" "file_2" "file 3"`?**

Currently my only workaround is:

```
while read line; do backup "$line"; done < <(mycmd)
```

Comment: You don't want to parse the output of `ls` (see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); you should use globs instead of the command substitution, i.e., instead of `$(ls -1 *)` just `*`. So, the answer is "you can't", but also "you shouldn't use command substitution in the first place".

Comment: @BenjaminW.: I have already put it in my question. Please read before commenting :-)

Comment: `while read line; do backup "$line"; done` doesn't work adequately. Your code will misbehave with filenames that end with whitespace, filenames that contain literal backslashes, and filenames that contain literal newlines.

Comment: `for file in *; do backup "$file"; done` will do the proper thing and is completely POSIX.

Comment: @PSkocik: Backuping * was only a simplification. In the general I need to quote $(command) in general - for any command.

Comment: `$(command)` is the wrong tool if you want something safe for the general case. (And by the way, there's an actual builtin command named `command`, making it a questionable choice of placeholders).

Comment: How about posting the code for your `backup` script so that we can suggest improvements? As it is, you're looking for a file delimiter that is not a newline, for example what `find`'s `-print0` option provides. We can't help you with your code unless you include your code.

Comment: ...if you want to see examples of tools that are written to cover the general case, by the way, you might look at archivers such as (the GNU implementation of) `tar`, or `pax` -- you'll note that they support NUL delimiters when a stream of filenames needs to be passed around. `find -print0`, `pax -0`, `xargs -0`, etc. exist for a reason.

Comment: I have edited the question and removed oversimplification so that it is no longer confusing. (It confused BenjaminW. and PSkocik).

Answer (score 6):

#### Lists of filenames (or command-line parameters) cannot safely be passed in line-oriented format without escaping.

This is because a command substitution evaluates to a C string. A C string can contain any character other than NUL.

Your intended use case is to generate a list of filenames. An individual filename can *also* contain any character other than NUL (which is to say: **filenames on popular operating systems are allowed to contain literal newlines**).

This is true for other command-line parameters as well: `foo$'\n'bar` is completely valid as an argument-list element.

It is thus literally impossible (without use of an agreed-upon escaping mechanism or higher-level format which one tool knows how to generate and the other knows how to parse) to represent arbitrary filenames in the output from a command substitution.

---

#### Safely processing a list of filenames as a string

If you want a stream to safely contain an arbitrary list of filenames, it should be NUL-delimited. This is the format produced by `find -print0`, for instance, or by the simple command `printf '%s\0' *`.

However, you can't read this into a shell variable, because (again) a shell variable *can't contain the NUL character literal*. What you *can* do is read it into an array:

```
files=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  files+=( "$filename" )
done < <(find . -name '*.txt' -print0 )
```

and then expand that array:

```
backup "${files[@]}"
```

---

#### Processing line-oriented content (known not to contain newline literals) safely

The above being said, you *can* read a series of lines into an array, and expand that array (but it isn't safe for the case here, where data is arbitrary filenames):

```
# readarray is a bash 4.0 builtin
readarray -t lines <(printf '%s\n' "first line" "second line" "third line")
printf 'Was passed argument: <%s>\n' "${lines[@]}"
```

will properly emit:

```
Was passed argument: <first line>
Was passed argument: <second line>
Was passed argument: <third line>
```

Comment: Nice answer Charles! Would `xargs` be a bad thing to use in this situation? Maybe for example ( `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} echo "{}"` )?

Comment: My hesitance to recommend `xargs` comes from how easy it is to use badly. `-0` helps its safety, but I'd argue that `-I` *hurts* it (given the number of caveats in the definition of that argument's behavior). That said, if `-I` is removed, I agree that `xargs -0` is safe.

Answer (score 1):

`for file in *; do backup "$file"; done` will do the proper thing and is completely POSIX.

To answer your question, you can use standard IFS-splitting on the outputted strings. 
IFS is normally ' '$'\t'$'\n'. Perhaps splitting on tabs or newlines alone would solve your problem.
Alternatively, you can try splitting on a highly unlikely character such as the vertical tab:

```
#ensure the outputed items are separated by the char we'll be splitting on
output=$(printf 'a b\vb\vc d') 
set -f #disable glob expansion
IFS=$'\v' 
printf "'%s' " $output; printf '\n'
```

The above prints `'a b' 'b' 'c d'`.

Comment: If you're going to suggest string-splitting, you'll need to advise the OP to disable glob expansion to make that safe in the presence of glob-like data elements.